# Microsoft Unity lose "line number" where the exception happened, what shall I do?

Tags: exception, unity-container, line-numbers

In a Release Build, during Microsoft Unity resolving, if any exception throws up, the StackTrace has no "line number" where the exception happened.
Without such information, debugging might be troublesome....
How do you guys handle it?

I suppose this is due to Microsoft Uniy use Reflection.Emit. 
Is my guess correct?

below is the example

---

```
Project ABC uses Microsoft Unity to resolve ViewModel XYZ during initilization.
XYZViewModel constructor throws an exception. 

Source : Microsoft.Practices.Unity
Message : Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "XYZViewModel", name = "(none)".

Exception occurred while: Calling constructor XYZViewModel().

Exception is: Exception - test exception StrackTrace line number
```

---

At the time of the exception, the container was:

```
  Resolving XYZViewModel,(none)

  Calling constructor XYZViewModel()
////// no line number in XYZViewModel code 

Type : Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException
TargetSite : System.Object DoBuildUp(System.Type, System.Object, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride])
StackTrace :    at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\UnityContainer.cs:line 515
////// has line number in Microsoft Unity code 

   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\UnityContainer.cs:line 173
///// has line number in Microsoft Unity code
```

Comment: Usually you need to ask the C# compiler to generate .pdb (symbol files) along with the assemblies (exe/dll), so that when the application executes, the line number information can be printed out.

Comment: administrator: Lex's comment is the correct solution, however he used comment instead of answer, how could i close the question?

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki. Answer is in a comment. Anyone finding this topic in a search will see there is an answer and is more likely to look in for a hopefully useful answer.

"Usually you need to ask the C# compiler to generate .pdb (symbol files) along with the assemblies (exe/dll), so that when the application executes, the line number information can be printed out. –  [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li)